# System Application was uninstalled and could not be recovered in android

Tags: root-access, contacts, system-apps, 7.1-nougat, f-droid

I have rooted my device. I have installed crDroid-7.1.2-20171202-j5nlte-v3.8.3 and android 7.1.2

I am using j5nlte model of samsung.
I have accidentally uninstalled contact and contact storage applications since my device was already rooted.
After the uninstall process, I have installed `simple contacts` application from `f-Droid`
When I am willing to create a new contact I could not create the contact and the system says

```
No app from this device
```

As I think, the problem was "contact storage application was uninstalled".
I have downloaded below [application](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/contacts-storage-google/contacts-storage-7-1-2-release/contacts-storage-7-1-2-android-apk-download/) to install the contact storage application. I could not installed and the error was

```
The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name
```

I can restore the device to get my system apps but I can't restore since I have some other issues.

Is there any way to get my system apps back. Do I have any method to save contacts without contact storage apk?

Answer (score 0):

Afraid you need to re-install your ROM. Until you can do that, you can e.g. use [OpenContacts](https://f-droid.org/packages/opencontacts.open.com.opencontacts/) from F-Droid. This is an addressbook/dialer that comes with its own contacts storage no other app has access to (privacy-focused), so it should work in your current situation.

Comment: Open contact app was installed but could not open. It always says "keep stopping"

Comment: Sad to read that – but I don't know why that happens. Maybe ask the dev in [the app's issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/sultanahamer/OpenContacts/issues)? Ah, [here's the issue](https://gitlab.com/sultanahamer/OpenContacts/issues/114), someone else experienced this as well. Maybe join in there, as the original reporter didn't respond anymore? The app is actively maintained and the author seems very "responsive".

Comment: thanks, @lzzy for the help